# The issue is with connecting to the socket server in Laravel using Laravel Echo

Tags: laravel-echo, pusher-js, laravel-websockets

"I am working on a project using Laravel Broadcast and the package `beyondcode/laravel-websockets`. When I use Pusher.js directly, the connection and operations are successful, but when I use Laravel Echo, there is no connection established with the socket server."

in file js:

```
pusher code:
Pusher.logToConsole = true;
var pusher = new Pusher('a12bc34', {
    cluster: 'mt1',
    encrypted: false,
    forceTLS: false,
    wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
    wsPort: 6001,
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('internal-transfer-forms');
channel.bind('eventInternalTransferForm', function (data) {
   
});
```

```
laravel echo code:
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Pusher.logToConsole = true;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'a12bc34',
    cluster: 'mt1',
    encrypted: false,
    wsHost: '127.0.0.1',
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
});

Echo.channel(`internal-transfer-forms`)
    .listen('eventInternalTransferFormd', (e) => {
       
    });
```

"Based on the research I conducted and the question I asked in Telegram groups, unfortunately, I couldn't find the solution myself. It seems that the issue is more related to data transmission than connection, as I'm not even able to establish a connection. However, with Pusher.js, the connection and operations are successful."

Answer (score 0):

Please check below status
Step 1 :

```
Command : php artisan vendor:publish --provider="BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSocketsServiceProvider" --tag="migrations"
```

Step 2 :

```
php artisan migrate
```

Step 3 :
You need to publish the WebSocket configuration file:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSocketsServiceProvider" --tag="config"
```

Step 4

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

Step 5

Http

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID={yourid}

PUSHER_APP_KEY={yourKey}

PUSHER_APP_SECRET={yourKeySecret}

PUSHER_HOST=

PUSHER_PORT=

PUSHER_SCHEME=

PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

REDIS_PREFIX=

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT=6001
```

If you are using https then change below thing in .env

Https

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher


PUSHER_APP_ID={yourid}

PUSHER_APP_KEY={yourKey}

PUSHER_APP_SECRET={yourKeySecret}

PUSHER_HOST=

PUSHER_PORT=

PUSHER_SCHEME=

PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

REDIS_PREFIX=

//for this parameter added if are using https give you ssl certificate path

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT = /var/www/html/b_laravel/ssl_cert/apache-selfsigned.pem

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK   = /var/www/html/b_laravel/ssl_cert/apache-selfsigned-key.pem

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE = ""

LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_PORT=6001

config/broadcasting.php
```

In this if Two way Setup if you are using http then socket work on ws and if you are using https
Wss

1)If You are using Http then below change in your config/broadcasting.php file

Reference site : https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher

```
    'pusher' => [

    'driver' => 'pusher',

    'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),

    'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),

    'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),

    'options' => [

        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),

        'encrypted' => true,

        'host' => '127.0.0.1',

        'port' => 6001,

        'scheme' => 'http'

    ],

],
```

2)If You are using Https then below change in your config/broadcasting.php file

```
'pusher' => [

            'driver' => 'pusher',

            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),

            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),

            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),

            'options' => [

            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),

            'host' => '127.0.0.1',

            'encrypted' => true,

            'port' => 6001,       

            'scheme' => 'https',

            'debug' => true,

            'useTLS' => true,

            'curl_options' => [

            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,

            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,

            ]

    ],


'client_options' => [

    'verify' => false,

    // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html

],
```

Step 6
config/websockets.php

```
1)If You are using Http then below change in your config/websockets.php file




'apps' => [

        [

            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),

            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),

            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),

            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),

            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),

            'capacity' => null,

            'enable_client_messages' => false,

            'enable_statistics' => true,

        ],
 2)If You are using Https then below change in your config/websockets.php file




'apps' => [

        [

            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),

            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),

            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),

            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),

            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),

            'capacity' => null,

            'enable_client_messages' => false,

            'enable_statistics' => true,

        ],
```

In ssl part you have to add below three parameter

1)verify_peer
2)verify_peer_name
3)allow_self_signed

```
'ssl' => [

        /*

         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which

         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the

         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained

         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.

         */

        'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),


        /*

         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for

         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.

         */

        'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),


        /*

         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.

         */

        'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),


        'verify_peer' => false,

        'verify_peer_name' => false,

        'allow_self_signed' => true,

    ],
```

Step 7

routes/web.php

```
Add this line



Route::post('/broadcasting/auth', function () {

    return Auth::user();

    });
```

Step 8
config/app.php

```
In order to turn on broadcasting for any Laravel application, we need to go to config/app.php and uncomment:


App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

Step 9

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

Step 10
Change in resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

window.axios = axios;


let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');


if (token) {

    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;

} else {

    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');

}



window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


/**

 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening

 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting

 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.

 */


import Echo from 'laravel-echo';


import Pusher from 'pusher-js';



window.Pusher = Pusher;

//console.log(window.location.hostname);

window.Echo = new Echo({

    broadcaster: 'pusher',

    key: '{yourKey}',

    cluster: 'mt1',

    wsHost: window.location.hostname,

    wsPort: 6001,

    wssPort: 6001,

    forceTLS: true,

    disableStats: true,

    

});


If you are using http then you to connect using below code
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({

    broadcaster: 'pusher',

    key: '{yourKey}',

    cluster: 'mt1',

    wsHost: window.location.hostname,

    wsPort: 6001,

    wssPort: 6001,

    forceTLS: false,

    disableStats: true,

    

});
```

Please checked how to install supervioser and virtulhost in laravel websocket Please check link.
[laravel websocket setup and example how to use it](https://myphpinformation.blogspot.com/2024/01/laravel-websocket-setup-and-example-how-to-use-it.html)

Comment: I have already gone through all the steps you mentioned multiple times, and my main issue is that when I use pusher.js code directly in the frontend without using Laravel Echo, the socket connection is successfully established and my data is transferred. However, when I use Laravel Echo, the connection is not established from the beginning. Even in a new project, Laravel Echo doesn't work at all. Also, I should mention that I did not put the frontend code (related to Laravel Echo) in the bootstrap.js file; I placed it in another js file in the public directory.

Comment: can you checked with boostrap.js is it working ?

Comment: "I created a new project and tested it, but it still didn't work. However, I don't want to use Vite or anything else."

Comment: step 1 : Go TO vite.config.js add resources/js/app.js

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                "resources/css/app.css",
                "resources/scss/app.scss",
                "resources/js/app.js",
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

step 2 : after in your blade file added 

@vite(["resources/js/app.js"])


step 3 : npm run build

Comment: The resources have been checked and executed previously, but unfortunately, it's still not working. Right now, I've placed the Laravel Echo code in the JS file inside the public directory and added it to my project in the usual way. Do I need to make any changes to the code I've placed?

Comment: just checked in network is app.js in added for not. in my path is node_modules/.vite/deps/laravel-echo.js

Comment: The addition has been made, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Laravel websoket connection is successfully but your problem is that message not sent.
then please how to call event in controller?

Comment: Thank you very much, my dear friend, my issue has been resolved. The problem was with the cluster: 'mt1', because I had used a package to launch a socket server and hadn't considered this option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

use Pusher\Pusher;

class ChatController extends Controller

{

    public function index()

    {

        return view('chat');

    }

    public function sendmessage(Request $request)

    {

        //dd($request->all());

        $sendData['name'] = $request->your_name;

        $sendData['message'] = $request->send_meesage;

        $paramater['chanel'] = "guest_user";

        $paramater['event'] = "ChatEvent";

        $paramater['data'] = $sendData;

        try {

        $pusher = new Pusher(

            

            config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'),

            config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'),

            config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id'),

            config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.options', []),

             new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]),

        );      

           $pusher->trigger($paramater['chanel'], $paramater['event'], $paramater['data']);

        } catch (Exception $e) {

        // Handle Pusher API error

            // You might log the error, notify administrators, or respond to the client accordingly

          dd($e->getMessage());

        }

        return Redirect::to('/chat')->with(['type' => 'success','message' => 'Your message sent sucessfully']);

    }

    public function getmessage()

    {

        return view('get_message');

    }

}
```

For message or change sent to laravel websocket
add name space  :

```
use Pusher\Pusher;
```

in your controller

```
$sendData['name'] = $request->your_name;

        $sendData['message'] = $request->send_meesage;

        $paramater['chanel'] = "guest_user";

        $paramater['event'] = "ChatEvent";

        $paramater['data'] = $sendData;

        try {

        $pusher = new Pusher(



            config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'),

            config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'),

            config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id'),

            config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.options', []),

             new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['verify' => false]),

        );      

           $pusher->trigger($paramater['chanel'], $paramater['event'], $paramater['data']);

        } catch (Exception $e) {

        // Handle Pusher API error

            // You might log the error, notify administrators, or respond to the client accordingly

          dd($e->getMessage());

        }
you can send your data using above example. i think you have to use laravel boardcast event but i facing same issue so i have solution above example
```